# Redirect back to previous page in PHP

Tags: php, html, navigation

How do I redirect to a previous page using `header("Location:...")` ? The problem occurs when a user is scrolling down in a page to find a link for example, then clicks it - opens another page, clicks the link I've given "Go back to links (`header("Location:links.php");`)", but when the user clicks it, it will head to previous page but on the top part of the page.

The user must scroll down again where he found the link he just clicked (which is frustrating). Is there a php code like the *'back'-button* used in web browsers where you will go back to the exact location and page right before you click something else?

Comment: `header("Location:links.php#anchor");` ought to work. Or assign a session name to the anchor.

Comment: See this answer on SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/22490864/ it uses sessions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try this

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Note that this may not work with secure pages (HTTPS) and it's a pretty bad idea overall as  the header can be hijacked.

or

```
header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`

**'HTTP_REFERER'**

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` is not always reliable.

Comment: Has worked for me at least. Sessions another technique

Comment: Oh it works, in many circumstances, but it's not always reliable. I would have to find the related pages for that, but I don't have time right now to Google this. But from memory, it's not the best method to use; just saying.

Comment: I know, it's not the best method. Not good especially on HTTPS.

Comment: There was a page/question on SO about a month or so ago, where they had discussed a similar issue, and someone had devised a genius way for doing this, and for the life of me, I never did find it again. It may very well be inside one of my favorites, but that could take a while lol

Comment: Will be glad to see it :) Patiently waiting

Comment: I found this as to why using `HTTP_REFERER` is not reliable: => http://stackoverflow.com/a/5934792/ and I think I may have found that method using sessions http://stackoverflow.com/a/13703882/

Comment: Sessions with Token would be a reliable form :)

Comment: Yes, totally. I've used such a method for a login script I made some time ago. Works beautifully.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you should add some javascript to the page to perform scrolling.
Here is an example of such implementation with Jquery: [how to remember scroll position of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744145/how-to-remember-scroll-position-o-page)